# Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) on a react-native 0.63 project

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I've inherited a React Native project and it's been giving me headaches for weeks now.
The current problem I have is this error:

> `Invariant Violation:  Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling run application)`

The only problem is I don't know how to implement that in the codebase I've been given.

This is the ***index.js*** file I have:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {registerScreens} from './src/components/screens';
import {store} from './src/model/store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

registerScreens(Provider, store);
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        id: 'loginStack',
        options: {
          topBar: {
            visible: false,
          },
        },
        children: [
          {
            component: {
              id: 'login',
              name: 'Login',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
});
```

These are the dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "AgriPrecise",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "android_release": "react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.13",
    "@turf/area": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/circle": "^6.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "node": "^14.4.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "pretty-format": "^26.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.63",
    "react-native-appstore-version-checker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-color-picker": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-indicator": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^6.7.5",
    "react-native-netinfo": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-password-strength-meter": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-photo-view": "https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^9",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "realm": "^6.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "turf-line-to-polygon": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help. I'm ready to start crying on my keyboard at this point.

I tried using `AppRegistry.registerComponent()` in the index.js file like so but that didn't work

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {registerScreens} from './src/components/screens';
import {store} from './src/model/store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () =>
 Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        id: 'loginStack',
        options: {
          topBar: {
            visible: false,
          },
        },
        children: [
          {
            component: {
              id: 'login',
              name: 'Login',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
}));
registerScreens(Provider, store);
```